# Unable to display TabBar in View Controller iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

When a push notification is received, I am trying to navigate to a table view controller (`ReportTVC`). The Hierarchy of the view controllers in my storyboard is as shown below.

TabBarController -> Navigation Controller (Storyboard ID: CasesNavController) -> TableViewController (`CasesTVC`) -> TableViewController (`CaseSummaryTVC`) -> TableViewController(`ReportTVC`)

The `ReportTVC` is being displayed with the navigation controller as expected, but when I navigate back to the CasesTVC, I should have a TabBar with the tabs, **but this is missing**.

Can someone please advise how I could resolve this ?

**In AppDelegate.swift:**

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let navController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController as! UINavigationController

let reportTVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReportTVC") as! ReportTVC
reportTVC.obtainDoctorReport = true
reportTVC.caseId = caseId


navController.pushViewController(reportTVC, animated: true)
self.window?.rootViewController = navController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Make UITabBarController your root view controller and push Navigation Controller

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're setting the NavigationController to the as rootViewController you need to set the TabBarController as the root.

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let navController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Nav") as! UINavigationController
let tabController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tab") as! UITabBarController

let reportTVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReportTVC") as! ReportTVC
reportTVC.obtainDoctorReport = true
reportTVC.caseId = caseId

navController.pushViewController(reportTVC, animated: true)
tabController.setViewControllers([navController], animated: false)
self.window?.rootViewController = tabController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

You shouldn't forget that you also need the add the other ViewControllers in the TabBarViewController.